# Error adding Panel to JFrame in NetBeans

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans

So I made a JPanel and a JFrame using the Design functions in NetBeans and when I try to drag the panel onto the JFrame, I get the error "The component cannot be instantiated. Please make sure it is a JavaBeans component."

What I did was create an empty Frame and then create the Panel and put it all together using the panels, buttons, and text fields. I didn't modify the source code or anything.  Is there some kind of code I need to add into the panel to make it work with the JFrame? Or perhaps I missed a step in the design tab? I've included a picture that shows exactly what it is I made.

[jpanel](http://i50.tinypic.com/swy9hu.png)

Comment: Clean and build the project. What version of Netbeans are you using.  If you're using Netbeans 7+, you can check the `messages.log` found in `C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\{netbeans version}\var\log` and check for the exception that caused the problem

Comment: Wow, that was a simple fix! Thank you! If you would, go ahead and repost this comment as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Posted as requested :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clean and build the project (and sub projects as required).

If you're using Netbeans 7+, you can check the `messages.log` found in `C:/Users/{username}/AppData/Roaming/NetBeans/{Netbeans version}/var/log` and check for the exception that caused the problem.

I think the new 7.2 beta reports the problems to the user now (thankfully).